# Only show PDO BindParam when data is posted

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi this will most likely be very simple answer but I wanted to know how to run a BindParam only when an variable is not empty below is some example code:

```
// Adds variable name from input POST
$post_status = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'search_status', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$post_firstname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'search_firstname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM candidate_information WHERE status = :status ';

//Checks to see if post is empty
if(!empty($post_firstname)) {
    $query .= 'AND firstname LIKE :firstname';
    $post_firstname = '%'.$post_firstname.'%';
}

$stmt_main_table = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt_main_table->bindParam(':status', $post_status, PDO::PARAM_INT);
// Need a way to only call bindParam if $post_firstname is not empty
$stmt_main_table->bindParam(':firstname', $post_firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt_main_table->execute();
```

I know I could always wrap the `bindParam` in `if(!empty($post_firstname)) { }` but I was unsure if this was the correct way as eventually I want to add multiple search options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I normally don't use `bindParam` in a situation like that.

Instead, I fill an array with the necessary key-value pairs and send that to `execute()`:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM candidate_information WHERE status = :status ';
$params = array(':status' => $post_status);

//Checks to see if post is empty
if(!empty($post_firstname)) {
    $query .= 'AND firstname LIKE :firstname';
    $params[':firstname'] = '%'.$post_firstname.'%';
}

// etc.

$stmt_main_table = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt_main_table->execute($params);
```

Comment: Excellent @jeroen thank you. Sorry to ask but why isn't everything done this way rather than BindParam?

Comment: @JosephGregory I do (almost...) everything that way, whatever is easier / shorter :-)

Comment: But...what if you need to declare data types? You can't do that with this method. You can only compare strings with this. Be careful.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy That's a good point, but I don't encounter that a lot in practice. Mainly in `LIMIT` clauses and for the rest my data is normally already validated in other ways.

Comment: I only intend to use general text and numbers. The only other would be the email address but thats already been through a filter would that cause an issue?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy do you think it would be better just to wrap the BindParam in an if() statement?

Comment: @JosephGregory I don't see any problems, I also filter e-mail addresses, make sure my ID's are integers, etc.

Comment: This should be fine for you, just be careful is all i'm saying, and mostly to future Googlers. :) Think practically about your implementation...programming is a fickle woman.